# C weird array syntax in multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, pointer-arithmetic

I've known that this is true:

```
x[4] == 4[x]
```

What is the equivalent for multi-dimensional arrays? Is the following true?

```
x[4][3] == 3[x[4]] == 3[4[x]]
```

Comment: Did you try it?  What happened?

Comment: @Jim: x[4] == *(x + 4) == *(4 + x) == 4[x]

Comment: @JimClay Because `x[4] == *(x + 4)` so `4[x] == *(4 + x)`. The `[]` operator is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations.  I'm both fascinated and repelled at once.

Comment: @JimClay: ..and that's what C is really for. repelling and fascinating.

Comment: @Carl: Yes, sorry for offering a question as silly as that. I just had no compiler at this pc. Just tested online and it works. Pubby's explanation is more than enough, too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`x[y]` is defined as `*(x + (y))`

`x[y][z]` would become `*(*(x + (y)) + z)`

`x[y[z]]` would become `*(x + (*(y + (z))))`

---

`x[4][3]` would become `*(*(x + (4)) + 3)`   would become `*(*(x + 4) + 3)`

`3[x[4]]` would become `*(3 + (*(x + (4))))` would become `*(*(x + 4) + 3)`

`3[4[x]]` would become `*(3 + (*(4 + (x))))` would become `*(*(x + 4) + 3)`

Which means they are all equivalent.

Comment: In the case of a multidimensional array `int x[5][7]` you'd have `x[y][z]` defined as `*(x + 7*y + z)`. And `x[y]` would become `x + 7*y` i.e. the pointer to the indicated slice. But I believe the equivalences still hold, even if the expanded expressions are somewhat longer. If the compiler does accept the code at all, that is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In each case `x` is an array which decays to a pointer and then has pointer arithmetic performed on it.